# Weak stationary white noise sequence that are identically distributed but not independent

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stationary-processes

Let $\{Z_t\}$ be a sequence of random variables that are weakly stationary, i.e., $\mathbb{E}[Z_t]=0$ and $Var[Z_t]=\sigma^2$ and $Z_t$'s are uncorrelated, i.e., $cov(Z_s,Z_t)=0$ for all $t\neq s$. Can we create such a sequence of $Z_t$ that are not independent? Also, can we have the other way around, that is, $Z_t$'s are independent but not identically distributed?

**My try:**
For the first question, I am thinking of $Z_t = (-1)^tX_t$ where $X_t \sim N(0,1)$ but do not know how to show they are dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one *chooses* to define discrete-time white noise $\{Z_n\}$ as a sequence of zero-mean random variables that are uncorrelated but not necessarily independent, then there is nothing left to prove; the definition says it all. The $Z_n$'s are uncorrelated but need not be independent.

A far superior deinition of discrete-time white noise is as a sequence of zero-mean random variables that are independent (preferably identically distributed as well). The key point here is that with uncorrelated but dependent random variables, one cannot make a *linear* prediction (other than $0$) of the value of $Z_{n+i}$ given $Z_n$ (say) but it might be possible to make a *nonlinear* prediction.  In fact, the minimum mean-square error predictor of $Z_{n+i}$ when we know $Z_n$ is $E[Z_{n+i}\mid Z_n]$ which is, in general, a nonlinear function of $Z_n$. It sticks in my craw that one should be able to predict the value of white noise in any way (not just linear prediction), and the requirement of *independence* for white noise sequences eliminates this possibility:  if $Z_{n+i}$ and $Z_n$ are independent, then $E[Z_{n+i}\mid Z_n] = E[Z_{n+i}] = 0$.

Now, if one wants a sequence of zero-mean random variables that are uncorrelated but not necessarily independent, consider the following.

Let $\{X_{2n}\colon n\in \mathbb Z\}$ be a sequence
of *independent* identically distributed zero-mean standard normal random variables, and let $\{B_n \colon n\in \mathbb Z\}$ be a sequence of independent discrete random variables taking on values $+1$ and $-1$ with equal probability $\frac 12$ and independent of the $X_{2n}$'s. Now set $X_{2n+1} = X_{2n}B_n$ for each integer $n\in \mathbb Z$.
Verify that $X_{2n+1}$ is also a standard normal random variable and that $X_{2n}$ and $X_{2n+1}$ are *uncorrelated* normal random variables (hint: $E[X_{2n}X_{2n+1}] = E[X_{2n}^2]E[B_n] =0$). But note that $X_{2n}$ and $X_{2n+1}$ are **not independent** random variables; indeed, *conditioned* $X_{2n}=\alpha$ we know that the conditional distribution of $X_{2n+1}$ is that of a *discrete* random variable taking on values $\pm\alpha$ with equals probability instead of serenely continuing to be standard normal as independence demands.
Thus, $\{X_{m}\colon m\in \mathbb Z\}$ is a sequence of *uncorrelated* standard normal random variables (discrete-time white noise process according to the OP's definition) in which *pairs* $(X_{2n},X_{2n+1})$ are *not independent* (though they *are* uncorrelated). Call such pairs *doublets*. More generally, $(X_m, X_k)$ are either part of the same doublet (and hence uncorrelated but not independent) or belong to different doublets and thus are uncorrelated as well as independent.

Turning to the OP's other questions to whether the $Z_n$'s can be independent but not identically distributed, it is trivial to create such a "white noise process" according to the OP's definition. All we need is to have a sequence of independent zero-mean random variables with varying distribution functions, but all having the same finite variance $\sigma^2$; for example. $Z_n \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ if $n$ is odd and
$Z_n \sim U\left(-\sqrt{3}\sigma. +\sqrt{3}\sigma\right)$ if $n$ is even.It is not clear to me that this type of process has any particularly important role to play in any situation, but ymmv just as much as the OP's seems to be doing.

Comment: Thank you. You have answered my first question. Could you share your thoughts for my second question asking for "$Z_t$'s that are independent but not identically distributed"?

Comment: @Saeed See revised version.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, note the weak stationarity only puts restrictions on first two moments, but knowing first two moments is not enough to determine a general distribution.

Here's one construction. Let $f_{0}\left(z\right)=\left(2\pi\right)^{-1/2}z^{-1}\exp\left(-\left(\log z\right)^{2}/2\right)$ be the lognormal density. For $t\geq1$, let $f_{t}\left(z\right)=f_{0}\left(z\right)\left(1+\sin\left(2\pi\log z\right)/t\right)$ which is still a density. Let $\left\{Z_{t}\right\}_{t\geq0}$ be a sequence of random variables. Apply product measure method, they can be constructed independent, and each follows a distribution with density $f_{t}\left(z\right)$. Clearly they have distinct distributions. However, it follows Heyde (1963) that they have the same moments $\mathbb{E}\left[Z_{t}^{k}\right]=\exp\left(k^{2}/2\right)$ for all $k\geq1$, hence weakly stationary.